# How to format a variable as currency inside of a string

Tags: string, vba, variables, format, currency

All of the following is happening within an If Statement

I have a variable, Difference, that is the result of a subtraction of two monetary values.

I then have a another variable, Message, which looks as follows:

```
    If AssessedValue < ProposedValue Then
        Difference = Format(ProposedValue - AssessedValue, "Currency")
        Message = "Average value is " & Difference & " more than the current 
        appraised value. Do NOT recommend negotiations."
    Else
        Difference = Format(AssessedValue - ProposedValue, "Currency")
        Message = "Average value is " & Difference & " less than the current 
        appraised value. Recommend negotiations."
    End If
```

MY issue is that in the message that displays, the difference does not display as currency but just an un-formatted number instead of currency (Example of the message below)
     Average value is 21587 more than the current appraised value. Do NOT 
     recommend negotiations.

How can I get the 21587, in this example, to appear in the message as $21,587.00?

Thanks in advance for any help with this issue.
Kirk

Comment: Could you just format the difference as a number with 2 decimal points and add the $ to your text in the message?

Comment: Just use `Format(Difference, "Currency")`?  Or change `Difference` to be a `String` data type, instead of a numeric data type?  (Your posted code doesn't show how it has been declared, but I assume it is numeric or you wouldn't have an issue.)

Comment: Your question should include the declarations (`Dim` statements) for `Difference`, `AssessedValue` and `ProposedValue` variables, so that answerers don't have to speculate about important bits of context.

Comment: Sorry for not including my declarations, Difference is a long data type as some of my differences can be multi-million dollar amounts. Method 1 of YowE3K's response below solved my problem. Thanks again for everyone's input!

Comment: If `Difference` has been declared as a `Long` you need to realise that it will never include cents.  If cents are required, you should declare it as `Currency` (or as `String` if the message is the only place you are using it).

Comment: Would declaring it as a Double work as well?

Comment: A `Double` would be safe to store numbers (with cents) up to about $1,000,000,000,000.  A `Currency` can store numbers (with cents) up to $922,337,203,685,477.58.  So, in your situation, a `Currency` would allow you to handle numbers about 1000 times larger - but I assume that extra precision is unlikely to be an issue for you.  For the full data types summary, see this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary).

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to fix your issue:

1. Format `Difference` using a `"Currency"` format prior to including it in the string, e.g.

   ```
   Message = "Average value is " & Format(Difference, "Currency") & " more than the current appraised value. Do NOT recommend negotiations."
   ```
2. Declare `Difference` to be a `String` rather than a numeric type.  (I'm guessing you have declared it currently as a `Currency` type.)

   ```
   Dim Difference As String
   ```

   This will ensure that the result of `Format(ProposedValue - AssessedValue, "Currency")` is not converted back to a numeric value in order to be stored in your `Difference` variable.

Comment: @Mat'sMug When I first posted my original comment, I was thinking I was teaching the OP that, but then I noticed that they were already using it to set `Difference`, and the problem is almost certainly that `Difference` is a `Currency` type.